# How can i rotate a background image of a pseudo element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation

I know that i can rotate a background image by insert it in a pseudo element and make it rotate. 
But if i need to rotate a background image of a pseudo element how can i do?

This is my case:

```css
#button_motore {
 
 width: 150px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #41a8dc;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 10px;  
 
}

#button_motore:after {
 
 content: "";
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 position:absolute;
 background-color: #418FDC;
 display:inline-block;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-image: url(../img/eliche.png);
 background-size: 35px 35px;
 background-position: 7.5px 7.5px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 transition: 0.5s;
 
}

#button_motore:hover {

 background-color: #418FDC;

}

#button_motore:hover::after{
 
 background-color: #4172DC;
 -webkit-animation: motore_animation 0.4s linear;
 animation: motore_animation 0.4s linear;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  
}


#button_motore_content{
 
 font-size: 18px;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 right: 25px;
 
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="button_motore" name="motore"><font id="button_motore_content">Motore</font></button>
```

I want to rotate `eliche.png`. I can also use jQuery.

Comment: are you looking to spin it like with an animation, or just rotate it X degrees?

Comment: @mhodges just rotate it 360° an infinite number of times when `:hover`

Comment: You can't rotate a background image...it's not possible. Why can't you rotate the pseudo-element?

Comment: @Paulie_D I know but i need it to be fixed. Maybe i can create another pseudo-element (`::before`) and position it inside `::after` ?

Comment: Well you can use two pseudo-elements...layered. Obviously you can't put a pseudo-element inside another.

Comment: ^ simply place them on top of each other. and use the code in my answer to spin the element containing the background image

Comment: @Paulie_D I mean that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paulie_D mentioned, you cannot spin the background image, but you can spin the pseudo-element itself. That would look like the following:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

#button_motore:hover::after{
  background-color: #4172DC;
  /* obviously add prefixes */
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;   
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked by creating another pseudo element (`::before`) and give it these rules